# SAXParser implementation is skipping entities

Tags: java, saxparser

I have an implementation of org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler, it works fine except when it comes something like this:

```
<NAME>Ji&#345;&#237; B&#225;rta</NAME>
```

The character method is overriden as:

```
@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    if (currentElement) {
        currentValue = new String(ch, start, length);
        currentElement = false;
    }
}
```

But the char array that arrives to the method has only 'Ji', skipping the rest of the string.
I have another method to convert those entities to UTF-8, but I never get them, so I can't convert anything.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that the parser may not deliver all character data in one call. To be safe you must build the string from possibly several characters() invocations, bracketed by startElement()/endElement().

As a side note, why do you want to convert the "entities" to UTF-8? They are already converted to  UTF-16 characters.

Comment: I have solved the problem reading the content, unscaping char then parsing XML.

Comment: But that's work that the parser's supposed to do for you. Or?

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you describe is correct, your understanding is incorrect.

Try implementing `resolveEntity` in your Handler class.  Interestingly enough, the purpose of `resolveEntity` is to resolve an entity.  The string "Ji&#345;&#237;" starts with two characters "Ji" then contains two entities. "&#345;" is one entity and "&#237;" is another entity.

Another option is to not implement `resolveEntity` and to implement `skippedEntity` instead.